# Import "embed_video.fields" could not be resolved Pylance report Missing Imports

Tags: python, django-models, visual-studio-code, embed

I am working on this project and I am using VS-code editor.
I already installed Django-embed-video using pip install and I have installed the embed_video in settings under INSTALLED_APPS. This is the directory where the embed_video is installed on my pc:

`C:\Users\DEL.L\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages`.

but when I try to Import "`embed_video.fields` I get error message that says "`could not be resolved Pylance report Missing Imports`".

```
from django.db import models
from embed_video.fields import EmbedVideoField
# Create your models here.

class video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    url = EmbedVideoField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-added']
```

Comment: How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the command "`pip --version`" in the VS Code terminal to check the source of the module installation tool "pip", the module is installed here:

[image]

Then use "`pip show django-embed-video`" to view that the module has been installed successfully:

[image]

Also, please try to reload VS Code after the module installation is complete.

[image]

Reference: [Python environment in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if your Django virtual environment is activated. If it's not, run `& C:/Users/yourname/.virtualenvs/djangodev/Scripts/Activate.ps1` in your terminal.

If you've just installed Django-embed-video by using `pip install django django-embed-video` and have not closed VSCode yet, try to close and re-open it (maybe the installation had not been applied into Visual Studio).